# Javascript Battleship Game

Tags: javascript, arrays

I made a simple battleship game in javascript but there is not workimg correctly. I put the locations in an array and tried to delete guessed locations from that array by using splice method. But it alerts "MISS!" when i enter any number between 0 and 6.

Edit: I solved the problem by using parseInt method for promt.

```
var location1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location2 + 1;

var locations = [];
locations.push([location1, location2, location3]);

var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;

var isSunk = false;

while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Enter your guess(0 - 6)");
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    } else {
        guesses++;

        if (locations.indexOf(guess) > 0) {
            locations.splice(locations.indexOf(guess), 1);
            hits++;
            alert("HIT!");
            if (hits == 3) {
                isSunk = true;
                alert("You sank my battleship!");
            }
        } else {
            alert("MISS!");
        }
    }
}

var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, which 
means your shooting accuracy was " + (3 / guesses);
alert(stats);
```

Comment: The `.indexOf()` test should be `>= 0`

Comment: Also `prompt()` always returns a string.

Comment: @Pointy That's true but is javascript doing conversions between string and number automatically?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  The `.indexOf` method does `===`  comparisons.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing create Array with element like

```
var location=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and instead of deleting index of array delete element from it